# Salesforce Web Services API speed limit

Tags: rest, salesforce

I have a number of processes that download about 500,000 records each from Salesforce via their Web Services API. I've found that regardless of the complexity of my requests or the number of fields in each record, the download speed is always about 60 records per second. I've tried a number of things on my end like increasing the number of threads or the size of the buffer on the system receiving the data, and we don't have anything imposing a data speed limit within our organization. Does Salesforce throttle their API requests, and is there a way to remove the limit or at least speed up the response from Salesforce?

Comment: How do you download, REST API? SOAP? Rest bulk? Standard API or some custom web service written in apex? What speed do you get when you run same export with Data Loader?

Comment: It's a REST API connection via a reporting system. I don't have direct access to Salesforce so I can't get to the data loader.

Comment: 60 records / s is horribly low. I suspect that system's integration is inefficient. Do you even know if it acts as realtime proxy to SF or are you reading from a snapshot of SF database it took? It'll be hard to suggest optimisations (unique fields, indexes, skinny tables) without seeing the reasonably "raw" queries and their explain plans. You can sign up for free SF developer edition with 100k records capacity if you feel like experimenting

Comment: After some speed testing, log analysis, and a discussion with our web report software vendor, I've learned Salesforce is throttling the speed on their Web API. I've asked the department that has access to our Salesforce vendor (it's a third-party conduit, not Salesforce directly) if there's anything that can be done on their end. I am experimenting with it, and it definitely appears to be a download speed limit. If I make a simple select asking for all active Contacts outputting only the GUID, I get 1,500 rps. As I add fields to the output list, that speed gets slower.